# Filtering From 2 different tables in DAX

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I am having a little trouble figuring out how to properly filter from the one side through a many relationship and back through to another one sided table.

The issue is that a Customer can have multiple accounts which can have multiple Customers.

In the attached image I am trying to filter from a `Center#` through the `All Customer` level and then add a filter on the List table to get the correct open accounts.

So the example would be I am looking for all Customers that are associated with Center A and are attached to an account type A.

The inactive one to many relationship from `All Cust -> All Accts` is what needs to be active instead of the `All Cust -> Open table`.

I am currently using:

`CALCULATE([Cust Enrolls],CROSSFILTER('All Cust'[All Customer Number],'Open'[Primary Customer Number],Both))`

to be able to filter for the account type, but that table's customer is just the single primary customer.

Any ideas on how I should either rework the model or how to create the correct measure?

[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkaaE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend re-working your Data Model so that you have a clear 1-M for each dimension table to your fact tables. This will save you a tremendous amount of time and headaches now and in the future by structuring your data properly.

Comment: The issue is that a customer can have multiple accounts and the accounts can have multiple customers attached to them, and you go one step further and have a transactions table that has multiple transactions per account. So I am not really sure if it is possible to have a true 1 to many throughout the model. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you need to have a Customer Parent table, then each Customer will have multiple Accounts, and then those Accounts will have multiple transactions. This sounds like a fairly straightforward 1:M setup.